# Laravel is not working with require laravel/ui

Tags: php, laravel

On executing `composer require laravel/ui`

I am getting below problems

Using version ^3.2 for laravel/ui

```
./composer.json has been updated
```

Running composer update laravel/ui
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1**
- Root composer.json requires nesbot/carbon 2.0.0-beta.2 as 1.25.0, found nesbot/carbon[2.0.0-beta.2] but the package is fixed to 1.39.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

**Problem 2**
- Root composer.json requires kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2 ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2[1.0.0].
- kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2 1.0.0 requires nesbot/carbon ^2.0.0-beta.2 -> found nesbot/carbon[2.0.0-beta.2, ..., 2.46.0] but the package is fixed to 1.39.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

**Problem 3**
- Root composer.json requires laravel/ui ^3.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v3.2.0].
- laravel/ui v3.2.0 requires illuminate/console ^8.0 -> found illuminate/console[v8.0.0, ..., v8.33.1] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

Use the option `--with-all-dependencies (-W)` to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
[Composer File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghYkh.png)

Comment: what is your question here ? The problems are descriptive enough.

Comment: Sounds like it's conflicting with other packages you have installed.  I had a similar issue and realized that I had to update my Telescope package to get the composer command to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue resolved there is old version set on env variable on system that's why Laravel was installing on old version . I just add new env to system and start re installing the larval, I hope this will resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try running `composer update` alone to update your dependencies. Let it update and then run `composer require laravel/ui`

Comment: i tried to run but getting " Root composer.json requires php >=7.2.5 but your php version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement."

Comment: i update the php version from composer.json on the  project and composer.lock but still getting the same error

Comment: i just update my question with composer file screenshot

Comment: From your answer, I understand that your PHP version is outdated. Try updating PHP first. In case you are using windows you can check this https://www.wpblog.com/update-php-version-in-xampp/

Answer (score 0):

Try to run "composer install" or "composer update" and after that run "composer require laravel/ui"

Comment: i tried to run but getting " Root composer.json requires php >=7.2.5 but your php version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement."

Comment: i update the php version from composer.json on the project and composer.lock but still getting the same error

Comment: i just update my question with composer file screenshot

Comment: How about node.js, have you updated node.js

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependencies to your composer.json**:

```
"nesbot/carbon": "2.0.0 as 1.25.0"
 "kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2": "^1.0.0",
"laravel/ui": "^3.0",
```

Then run command

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mentioning the ui version, may be you are using an older version of laravel

like

composer require laravel/ui:^2.4

Comment: Package laravel/ui at version 2.4 has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version

Comment: the issue resolved there is old version set on env variable on system that's why laravel was installing on old version . i just add new env to system  and start re installing the larval,i hope this will resolve  my issue.